# Insert a variable to a list using its value

Tags: python, list, insert

Seems that python inserts variables to lists using their references. For example, the following code:

```
t=[[0],[1]]
t.insert(1,t[0])
t[0].append(0)
```

returns:

```
t= [[0, 0], [0, 0], [1]]
```

while the desired output is:

```
t= [[0, 0], [0], [1]]
```

Any idea how to handle this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome back again. You should use `copy.copy` if you want to copy the value instead of referencing it. Remember that `copy.copy` will only make a shallow copy, ie copy the first level of the object. Use `copy.deepcopy` if you have to copy more than one level.

```
import copy
t=[[0], [1]]
t.insert(1, copy.copy(t[0]))
t[0].append(0)
print t  # [[0, 0], [0], [1]]
```

Comment: Great. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You have to copy the list, you can use the built in function `list`, try:

```
>>> t=[[0],[1]]
>>> t.insert(1,list(t[0]))
>>> t[0].append(0)
>>> t
[[0, 0], [0], [1]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `[:]` for a shallow copy of a list:

```
t = [[0], [1]]
t.insert(1, t[0][:])
t[0].append(0)
```

Now:

```
>>> t
[[0, 0], [0], [1]]
```